# Contractivity of a projection on $C(\mathbb{T}^2)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, several-complex-variables, contraction-operator

Consider the $C^\star$ algebra of all complex-valued continuous functions on the 2-torus $\mathbb{T}^2$ with the sup norm. Let us consider the set $\{z^m w^n\}_{m,n\in \mathbb{Z}}$, whose span is dense in $C(\mathbb{T}^2)$. We define the projection $\phi: C(\mathbb{T}^2) \to C(\mathbb{T}^2)$, thus:

$z^m w^n \mapsto z^m w^n$ if $mn\geq 0$

$z^m w^n \mapsto 0$ if $mn < 0$

and extend it linearly on the closure.

The question is, **is this map contractive?**

I really don't know what would be a way to attack this problem directly. I have tried a few indirect approaches using positivity, without much success: since the map is unital, it is contractive iff it is positive. Positive elements of $C(\mathbb{T}^2)$ are not very easy to characterize, due to the absence of a Fejer-Riesz theorem in 2 variables, but still, one may write a strictly positive trigonometric polynomial in $(z,w)$ as a finite sum of absolute squares of polynomials in $(z,w)$. Annihilating the terms with opposite signs for the powers of $z$ and $w$, it is not direct to see if it is positive...

As for my background: I am familiar with basic complex analysis, the basics of $C^\star$ algebras and the theory of positive maps.

Comment: This is not a Schauder basis.

Comment: @Ruy, perhaps I am missing something here, please let me know: {z,w} form a separating subset for C(T^2), so, by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, the *-algebra generated by {1,z,w} is dense in C(T^2). This *-algebra is the span of {z^m w^n | m,n integers}, so z^m w^n should be a Schauder basis of C(T^2), in the sense that any element of C(T^2) is an infinite linear combination of these (wrt the norm topology)... right?

Comment: The answer to your last question is negative by the same reason that Fourier series do not always converge.

Comment: @Ruy, thank you very much for pointing this out. I now understand, and have updated the original question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map is not continuous, much less contractive (so there is no way to extend it by continuity beyond the trigonometric polynomials) for the following reason.  Consider the embedding of $C(\mathbb T)$ into $C(\mathbb T^2)$ in such a way that $z^m$ goes to $z^mw$.

If your map is bounded, it's restriction to the above copy of $C(\mathbb T)$ would send $z^m$ to itself if $m\geq 0$, and to zero otherwise, and it is well known that this map doesn't exist on $C(\mathbb T)$.

Comment: thanks, understood!