# Does the inclusion map satisfy Unique (CP) Extension Property?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Consider the $C^\star$ algebra $C(\mathbb{T}^2)$ of complex-valued continuous functions on the 2-torus with the sup norm. Let $S$ be the operator system that is the (norm) closure of the linear span of $\{z^m w^n| m,n \in \mathbb{Z}, mn \geq 0\}$. Let $i:S\to C(\mathbb{T}^2)$ denote the (canonical) inclusion map of $S$ in $C(\mathbb{T}^2)$. $i$ is completely positive (CP), and by Arveson's Extension Theorem, it must have CP extension(s) $\tilde{i}: C(\mathbb{T}^2) \to C(\mathbb{T}^2)$, such that $\tilde{i}|_S=i$. One such CP extension is, $\tilde{i}=\mathbb{I}_{C(\mathbb{T}^2)}$, which is, extending as the identity map on $C(\mathbb{T}^2)$. My question is, is it the *only* CP extension? Or, in other words, does the inclusion map have the unique extension property (CP) in this case? If not, what would be another example of a CP extension?

Perhaps an interesting point to note: the trivial extension doesn't work, as aptly demonstrated in the answer to a
[previous question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3972851).

Comment: Are you asking about uniqueness among maps from $C(\mathbb{T}^2) \to  C(\mathbb{T}^2)$?
Arveson's Extension Theorem usually apply to maps into $B(H)$, so a more general question would entail representing
$C(\mathbb{T}^2)\subseteq B(H)$, and then asking about uniqueness among CP  maps from $C(\mathbb{T}^2) \to  B(H)$.

Comment: @Ruy, actually I was asking for maps from $C(\mathbb{T}^2)$ to $C(\mathbb{T}^2)$. Of course, Arveson's extension theorem usually applies for maps into $\mathcal{B(H)}$, and we would need $C(\mathbb{T}^2)$ to be injective to apply the theorem in this case. I don't know, though, if it is injective... Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  the unique CP extension applies to the present situation.  It is in fact a consequence of the following more
general fact:

**Theorem**. Let $A$ be a unital C$^*$-algebra and let $\mathscr U$ be a set of unitaries in $A$,
generating $A$ as a C$^*$-algebra,  and  such that $1\in \mathscr U$.
Given a unital representation $\pi :A\to B(H)$, suppose that $\varphi :A\to B(H)$ is a completely positive map such that
$$
  \varphi (u)=\pi (u), \quad\forall u\in \mathscr U.
  \tag 1
  $$
Then $\varphi =\pi $.

*Proof*.  By Stinespring Theorem,  there exists a Hilbert space $\tilde H$, a  unital representation  $\tilde\pi:A\to B(\tilde H)$,
and a bounded operator $V:H\to \tilde H$, such that
$$
  \varphi (a)=V^*\tilde \pi (a)V, \quad\forall a\in A.
  \tag 2
  $$
Observing that both $\varphi $ and $\pi $ are unital maps, we deduce that $V^*V=1$, which is to say that $V$ is an isometry.

Notice that, for each $u$ in $\mathscr U$ we have
$$
  \pi (u) = \varphi (u) = V^*\tilde \pi (u)V,
  $$
so $\tilde \pi (u)$ commutes with $VV^*$ by Lemma (1), below.

Since the commutant of $VV^*$ is a closed $^*$-subalgebra, and since $A$ is generated as a C$^*$-algebra by $\mathscr U$, it
follows that $\tilde \pi (a)$ commutes with $VV^*$ for every $a$ in $A$.

From (2) we then deduce  that $\varphi $ is a $^*$-homomorphism, and then (1) implies that $\varphi =\pi $.   $ \tag*{$\square$}$

---

**Lemma 1**.  If $V:H\to\tilde H$ is an isometry, and $U$ is a unitary operator on $\tilde H$ such that  $V^*UV$
is unitary, then $U$ commutes with $VV^*$.

*Proof*.  Identifying  $H$ with  a subspace of $\tilde H$ via $V$,  we may write $\tilde H = H \oplus  H^\perp$, and hence $U$ may be
represented as a matrix
$$
  U = \pmatrix {A & B \cr C & D},
  $$
where $A = V^* UV$, hence $A$ is unitary.  It follows that
$$
  \pmatrix {1 & 0 \cr 0 & 1} =   \pmatrix {A & B \cr C & D}   \pmatrix {A^* & C^* \cr B^* & D^*} = \pmatrix {AA^* + BB^*
&\cdots  \cr \cdots & \cdots},
  $$
so $B=0$, and a similar argument proves that $C=0$.  This implies that $U$ commutes with
$$
  \pmatrix {1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0} = VV^*.
  \tag*{$\square$}
  $$

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!